# Why is there whitespace when opening a website with a width of 480px?

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, whitespace

I've been using mediaqueries for a while now and never had the problem that on the top and left of my website, there's a very small whitespace I can't find using " find elements ".

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aller Bold';
    src: url('FontFace/Aller_Bd.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aller Display';
    src: url('FontFace/AllerDisplay.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 480px;
}

/*NAV*/

#logo {
    display: none;
}

    #navigation {
        font-family: 'Aller Bold';
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #f07c00;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #navigation ul {
        display: none;
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    #navigation ul.expanded {
        display: block;
    }

    #navigation li a {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #666;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .menu_button {
        margin-right: 22px;
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
        color: #ffc;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


/*slideshow*/

.fadein { position:relative; width:480px; height:140px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; width:480px; height:140px;  }


/*table nieuwsoverzicht*/

table tr th.tgth {
    font-family: 'Aller Display';
    color: #f07c00;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}

table tr td.tgtd {
    font-family: 'Aller Bold';
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-left: 42px;


}

table tr td.tg-datum {
    font-family: 'Aller Bold';
    font-size: 6px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    color: #f07c00;
    padding-left: 42px;

}

table tr td.tg-leesmeer {
    font-family: 'Aller Bold';
    font-size: 6px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    color: #f07c00;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;


}

table tr td.tg-image {
    float: right;


}

hr {

    border-style: solid;
    color: black;
    border-width: 1px;

}

img.smallimg {

    float: right;
    width: 164px;
    height: 96px;

}


/*links*/

h1.links {

    font-family: 'Aller Bold';
    color: #f07c00;
    font-size: 24px;

}

a.links {

    font-family: 'Aller Bold';
    margin-left: 42px;
    font-size: 18px;


}


/*footer*/

footer {

    font-family: 'Aller Bold';
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: #f07c00;
    color: black;
    line-height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
}

#test {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

#linkcontact {


    margin-right: 32px;
}

#linklinks {

    margin-right: 40px;

}

#linkbronnen {

    margin-right: 40px;
}

a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" media="screen and (min-width: 480px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet480.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<script>

    var originalNavClasses;

    function toggleNav() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('navigation_list');
        var classes = elem.className;
        if (originalNavClasses === undefined) {
            originalNavClasses = classes;
        }
        elem.className = /expanded/.test(classes) ? originalNavClasses : originalNavClasses + ' expanded';
    }

    </script>

<body>
<main>

    <nav id="navigation">
        <img src="logo.jpg" id="logo">
        <a id="mobilemenu" class="menu_button" href="#footer_nav" onclick="toggleNav(); return false;">&#9776;  MENU</a>
        <ul id="navigation_list" role="navigation">
            <li><a href=#>Nieuws</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Info</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Bezienswaardigheden</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Keuken</a></li>
            <li id="rightnav"><a href=#>Steden</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <script>

        $(function(){
            $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
            setInterval(function(){
                        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                                .next('img').fadeIn()
                                .end().appendTo('.fadein');},
                    4000);
        });


        </script>

    <br> <br>

    <div class="fadein">
        <img src="sld1.jpg">
        <img src="sld2.jpg">
        <img src="sld3.jpg">
    </div>

    <br>

    <hr>

    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th class="tgth">De prachtige stad Rotterdam</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tgtd">Rotterdam is een havenstad gelegen in het westen van Nederland, in de provincie Zuid-Holland. De stad is gelegen aan de Nieuwe Maas,
                een van de rivieren in de delta die gevormd wordt door de Rijn en de Maas.
                De haven van Rotterdam, lange tijd de grootste ter wereld, is de grootste en belangrijkste van Europa. Het havengebied strekt zich uit over een lengte van 40 kilometer.</td>
            <td class="tg-image"><img class="smallimg" src="rotterdamsmall.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-datum">Datum: 09/07/2015</td>
            <td class="tg-leesmeer">Lees meer -></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <hr>


    <br> <br><br> <br><br> <br><br> <br>





    <footer>
        <div id="test">
        <a href="Bronnen" id="linkbronnen">Bronnen</a>
        <a href="Links" id="linklinks">Links</a>
        <a href="Contact" id="linkcontact">Contact</a>
        </div>
    </footer>


</main>
</body>
</html>
```

When you make sure the width of your browser is 480px wide, you'll see that on both left and top, there's a very small whitespace, which I'm looking to get rid of. Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Hello @MichaelJones, thank you for the fast response, I had margin:0 in my main element, not the body element.

Comment: no problem! :) Everyone makes mistakes :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding to your CSS the following:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

That should get rid of the white space.

Answer (score 0):

Simply it's by the browsers, I don't know why! Simply do this:

```css
/*
 (*) mean All Elements , this code remove all margin and padding from all element include html and body also  ^_^
*/
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```